# Is there a term for a polynomial with a constant term that is nonzero?

Tags: polynomials, terminology

This seems really basic, but I can't think of a term for a polynomial with a nonzero constant term.

Googling gives me lots of references to "nonzero constant term" and "non-zero polynomial" (not the same thing), but no specific term.

Comment: Why did someone downvote? It's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I do not think there is such a term. You could say either $P(0)\neq0$ or just nonzero constant term.

Comment: I don't think there is such a term.  A basic theorem in linear algebra states, "A matrix is invertible if and only if its characteristic polynomial has nonzero constant term," and the only other way I've ever heard it stated is "... if and only if zero is not a root of its characteristic polynomial."

Comment: If there were a term, I'm not sure it could be shorter or clearer than "with non-zero constant term".

Comment: I think I'm resigned to there not being a term.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone with better knowledge will swoop in with a proper term, but two options I can think of is "$P(x)$ with non-zero constant term" as a literal description, or "$P(x)$ not divisible by $x$".

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this concept has a widely used simple name. If you get tired of saying "polynomial with nonzero constant term," you could also write polynomials $P$ with $P(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: I wouldn't mind finding a simple name even if it's not widely used.  Can't find a name at all (other than descriptive phrases)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered a name for it but you can refer to it as : a polynonial which has $0$ as a root, or which is divisible by $x$.